# (Romans 8:26) "What" to pray And/Or "How" to pray of a specific prayer

Tags: greek, textual-criticism, translation-philosophy, grammatical-historical

I do Not have any comprehension and/or fluency in the Greek language(s).

However, I wanted to get a better understanding of Romans 8:26 which is related to prayer.

I might just be nit-picking.

As I was reviewing various Bible translations, I noticed that:

- some translations emphasize that we do Not know **What** to pray ( as in intent/objective/goal of a specific prayer)
- other translations emphasize that we do Not know **How** to pray ( as in nature/manner of a specific prayer)

Therefore, I was just curious as to what the various New Testament Greek Texts would state.  I posted the some different New Testament Greek Texts from https://biblehub.com/text/romans/8-26.htm

In any case, could someone please read & evaluate the different New Testament Greek Texts to see if they say "**What**" and/or "**How**"?
Is there some kind of Greek phrase or word that entails both "**What**" And "**How**" (which probably does Not exist in English)?

> Romans 8:25-27 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
> 25 But if we hope for what we do not see, with perseverance we wait
> eagerly for it. 26 In the same way the Spirit also helps our weakness;
> for we do not know **How** to pray as we should, but the Spirit Himself
> intercedes for us with groanings too deep for words; 27 and He who
> searches the hearts knows what the mind of the Spirit is, because He
> intercedes for the [a]saints according to the will of God.
>
> Romans 8:25-27 King James Version (KJV)
> 25 But if we hope for that we
> see not, then do we with patience wait for it. 26 Likewise the Spirit
> also helpeth our infirmities: for we know not **What** we should pray for
> as we ought: but the Spirit itself maketh intercession for us with
> groanings which cannot be uttered. 27 And he that searcheth the hearts
> knoweth what is the mind of the Spirit, because he maketh intercession
> for the saints according to the will of God.
>
> ΠΡΟΣ ΡΩΜΑΙΟΥΣ 8:26 Greek NT: Westcott and Hort 1881 Ὡσαύτως δὲ καὶ τὸ
> πνεῦμα συναντιλαμβάνεται τῇ ἀσθενείᾳ ἡμῶν· τὸ γὰρ τί προσευξώμεθα καθὸ
> δεῖ οὐκ οἴδαμεν, ἀλλὰ αὐτὸ τὸ πνεῦμα ὑπερεντυγχάνει στεναγμοῖς
> ἀλαλήτοις,
>
> ΠΡΟΣ ΡΩΜΑΙΟΥΣ 8:26 Greek NT: Westcott and Hort / [NA27 and UBS4
> variants] Ὡσαύτως δὲ καὶ τὸ πνεῦμα συναντιλαμβάνεται τῇ ἀσθενείᾳ ἡμῶν·
> τὸ γὰρ τί προσευξώμεθα καθὸ δεῖ οὐκ οἴδαμεν, ἀλλὰ αὐτὸ τὸ πνεῦμα
> ὑπερεντυγχάνει στεναγμοῖς ἀλαλήτοις,
>
> ΠΡΟΣ ΡΩΜΑΙΟΥΣ 8:26 Greek NT: RP Byzantine Majority Text 2005 Ὡσαύτως
> δὲ καὶ τὸ πνεῦμα συναντιλαμβάνεται ταῖς ἀσθενείαις ἡμῶν· τὸ γὰρ τί
> προσευξόμεθα καθὸ δεῖ, οὐκ οἴδαμεν, ἀλλ’ αὐτὸ τὸ πνεῦμα ὑπερεντυγχάνει
> ὑπὲρ ἡμῶν στεναγμοῖς ἀλαλήτοις·
>
> ΠΡΟΣ ΡΩΜΑΙΟΥΣ 8:26 Greek NT: Greek Orthodox Church Ὡσαύτως δὲ καὶ τὸ
> Πνεῦμα συναντιλαμβάνεται ταῖς ἀσθενείαις ἡμῶν· τὸ γὰρ τί προσευξώμεθα
> καθ’ ὃ δεῖ οὐκ οἴδαμεν, ἀλλ’ αὐτὸ τὸ Πνεῦμα ὑπερεντυγχάνει ὑπὲρ ἡμῶν
> στεναγμοῖς ἀλαλήτοις·

Answer (score 1):

The phrase in Greek is "το γαρ τι προσευξωμεθα" which is literally "the (thing) for which we-pray".  When translating Greek, you have to take your best guess on the meaning because it's a bit less precise (or, more accurately, it's precise in different ways) than English.  So some translators take "the for which" as "what" and some take "the for which" as "how".